# GCP Endpoint "Try this API" authorization URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to configure the "Try this API" feature in GCP Endpoint using a service account as authentication. I am using this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-custom
I have configured endpoint securityDefinitions as stated below.

```
securityDefinitions:  
  google_service_account_dev:  
    authorizationUrl: ""  
    flow: "implicit"  
    type: "oauth2"  
    x-google-issuer: "[...]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"  
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/[...]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"  
    x-google-audiences: "[...].appspot.com"
```

In the developer portal there is a message:
`"Try this API" is disabled for users on this page for the following reasons: 
"Try this API" requires an authorization URL to be specified in the API spec for the "google_service_account_dev" security requirement.`

In documentation "authorizationUrl" component is empty, so documentation is buggy.
How it should be configured to allow to use "Try this API" feature?

---

EDIT:
I tried to follow this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/dev-portal-explore-api
It seems out of date. According to the document in the Portal settings there should be `APIs Explorer Settings` section, but it is not present. Any idea where I should paste the API Key?

Comment: The issue here is that you are trying to authenticate using a service account. Could you try to follow [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/dev-portal-explore-api) and let me know if this works for you?

Comment: @tzovourn I have edited question after I tried to follow the instruction.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this issue. Although following the doucmentation of "Try this API" I need to Deploy the API backend. Could you share with me the exact steps of reproduction and in which service you deployed the API's backend as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/deploy-api-backend#app-engine)?

Answer (score 1):

I've spend a lot of time too to make the "Try this API" feature available on our GCP API Endpoints Portal (not public). And after a couple of month to struggling with that, yesterday I found my answer on the [GCP API management doc limitations](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/dev-portal-overview). And as it's well specified :

> The Endpoints service **must be** **publicly** accessible in order to use the
> Try this API panel. Requests will fail if other authentication (such
> as IAP) is configured on the Endpoints service.

So.. I've deactivate it cause our API must be authenticated. :/ Sorry for this bad news, but I hope at least that will not waste your time with that.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue, I just found out that the actual oauth flow works behind upon trying with Postman and passing correct bearer token despite issues in Developer Portal UI. Just leave authorizationUrl and scopes blank/empty on your config.

The only challenge here on how to bypass this oauth on the Developer Portal side.